# Using Setters within a Scala method

Tags: scala, tdd

**Introduction**

**Aim:** to use (multiple) setters in a Scala method.

**Test**

```
test("testCity") {
  val numberSequences = new NumberSequences()
  numberSequences.test("utrecht")
  assert("utrecht" === numberSequences.city)
}
```

**Code**

```
var _city: String = null 

def city_=(_city:String) = this._city = _city  
def city = this._city

def test(s: String)  : String = {
  city_=(s)
}
```

**Output**

The error indicates that there is a type match, which is strange as `numberSequences.city_=("utrecht")` in the test works.

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\path\to\developme
nt\scalaNumberSequences\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\path\to\development\scalaNumberSequences\src
\main\scala\com\utrecht\numbersequences\NumberSequences.scala:86: type mismatch;

[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: String
[error]     city_=(s)
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 10, 2014 8:53:37 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test(s: String)  : String = {
  city_=(s)
}
```

Here you set the variable of the var `city_`, but your method signature says it should return a String, the return type of a function comes from the last line and assignment has no return type, either return some string at the end:

```
def test(s: String): String = {
  city_=(s)
  s
}
```

Or make it a setter-like method and return unit:

```
def test(s: String): Unit = {
  city_=(s)
}
```